# Can i repost my deleted question

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

A month ago I posted a puzzle which was combination of two riddles and I asked about the link between them. Both riddles could be solved individually. But I found a mistake in my research for the first riddle (sorry for that). So the whole puzzle had to be deleted with the help of moderator. But the second riddle was alright. So can I post the second riddle now, separately?

If I am allowed then I would request our moderator @Emrakul not to disclose the answer as it was him who helped me to delete it and I gave him the answer to the second puzzle with the deletion request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Feel free. My zips are lipped about your *dark secrets*.

(I don't remember the answer(s), anyway!)

Comment: thanks...you will remember when i'll post the riddle. One more thing. Is a question deleted with the help of single moderator or more are involved?

Comment: [Here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/26081/the-magnet-for-you) is the question.

Comment: @manshu Moderators can delete questions by themselves. Three or more regular users can delete and undelete questions, too. And... I vaaaguely remember that riddle, yeah! Still don't quiiite remember the answer. Will watch it.